# Appending multiple button clicks to a list using Flask

Tags: python, flask

First time posting. I appreciate any help. I'm taking a list of items and displaying them on a page using a for loop. Each item is a button instead of a hyperlink. I'm trying to make it so the user can click multiple buttons as "choices" and have the value for each button appended to a list for further processing. So far, nothing happens on click. I try to go to the page I've created as a test to view results and I get a 404.

In my template I use this For loop to get the whole list on the page. Each list item's text is clickable like a button. But I'm just not sure where to go from here.

```
<form action="/choices" method="post">

      {% for i in range(0, toplen) %}

        <button class="choice-button" type="submit" name="{{ top[i] }}" 
           value="{{ request.form.choice }}">{{ top[i] }}</button>
        <br>

       {%endfor%}

    </form>
```

Here is what I have in Flask:

```
@app.route('/choices', methods=["POST"])
def choices():
    choice_list = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        choice = request.form.choice
        choice_list.append(choice)
        return render_template("choices.html", choice_list=choice_list)
    else:
        return render_template("restaurant_list.html")
```

Right now I'm just trying to get the list to show on the choices.html page but I just get the 404. What I'd really like to do is have the user click as many buttons as they like, and have the results show up in real time on the same page. Like a confirmation of each choice.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense. If more info is needed I can provide it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want your button to submit the data entered in the form, you need `type="submit"`.   I'd venture to suggest that for user selection of multiple choices you might be better off with an `<input type="checkbox"` element in your Jinja `for` loop, then a single submit button.   For instant feedback you can use Javascript.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it and now it looks like it's trying to do something but I'm getting a 500 error. I'm not sure how to tell it to grab the "name" value in the button.

Comment: My original idea was to have the checkbox and single submit but I was thinking it would look cooler to have the choices populate in the middle of the page in real time using the list of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use `request.form['choice']`

Also just a note, if you need this route to handle the GET request, you need to  add `methods=['GET', 'POST']` as right now the route will only handle the POST request.